# Can we make the job search link consistent in its capitalization with the rest of the links?

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

As can be seen in the image below, the link isn't capitalized in the same way as the rest of the links it is inline with:

> [image]

It just seems odd to me in the way that it is right now.

(It might just be matching the tag slug but it seems out of place, IMO)

Comment: How about "Jobs in <tagname>"?  The word "Jobs" can be capitalized, and the tag name can remain lowercase.

Comment: It matches the tabs below it; every entry is capitalized except for the last "unanswered" tab.

Comment: @DavyM or maybe the that's another issue? :P (Note on the smiley, I hate the fact that I have to use it to convey humour, but otherwise it might come across a blunt)

Answer (score 8):

How about "Jobs in <tagname>"?  The word "Jobs" can be capitalized, and the tag name can remain as is.  It would take up only a few more characters.

There is no need to create a mapping between a tag name and a properly capitalized job display name.  One could just easily change the text slightly from "<tagname> jobs" to "Jobs in <tagname>".  I think "Jobs in jquery" is good enough.

Answer (score 6):

Honestly, `Php jobs` would look even more awkward, I can't think of a successful heuristic for properly capitalizing technology and brand names (think [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) -> PHP, [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) -> jQuery, [nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) -> Node.js, [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) -> iOS).

You would need a mapping between a slug and a properly capitalized name, it would have to be maintained somehow (probably through the community in some fashion, as that would make sense).

In short, implementing this is likely to be very expensive, for a relatively small potential gain.

I won't [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this as [there is a chance](https://i.imgur.com/WHGi867.gifv) of this happening, albeit asymptotic to 0. But don't get your hopes up ;)

Comment: When writing it up, it hit me that it would look odd and I also thought of your suggestion too. One thing I didn't consider which @rgettman mentioned was reformulating it to: '*Jobs in <tagname>*' or some variant of that, I believe that'd work. As for '*But don't get your hopes up ;)*', I will keenly be awaiting this update to drop within 6-8 weeks.

Comment: We had a "pretty name" field during the Documentation experiment. Wonder if that plumbing is gone...?